# ¿Se puede dar fuente a un textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Es posible hacer que se pueda cambiar el estilo de lo que escriba ahí, como cambiar el color o el tamaño de las letras.
Si no es así, ¿que alternativas existen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si se puede aqui te dejo un ejemplo:

```css
#textarea {
font-family: arial, verdana, ms sans serif;
font-size: 20pt;
color: red;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Recuerda que aunque es una muy mala practica hacer lo siguiente(me refiero a meter el css en el mismo html, en vez de en otro archivo de lectura por cascada, es decir "ejemplo.css"), tambien se puede hacer:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#textarea {
font-family: arial, verdana, ms sans serif;
font-size: 20pt;
color: red;
background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puede cambiar con css ejemplo:

```css
#textArea{
width:100px;

background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<textArea id='textArea'>hola</textArea>
```

Una alternativa seria usar un `div` que tenga la propiedad `contentEditable=true`

```css
#div1{
width:100px;

background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='div1' contenteditable=true>hola</div>
```

Comment: Quisiera que se pudiera editar como si fuera un documento.

Comment: @IsmaelSalasLópez como se edita un documento?

Comment: Bueno, a lo mejor sería más útil si te digo que quiero hacer un editor como al estilo de un blog, utilizando un textarea y agregándole botones. ¿Con contentEditable=true sería suficiente para poder modificar el estilo del contenido del textarea?

Answer (score 0):

```
  textarea {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px !important;
  }
```

Este metodo me sirvió en mi código. Ójala les sirva.

Comment: Para que tu respuesta sea de mayor utilidad, pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente qué hace este código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.